'schematool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, in win 10 when I try to run hive commands
Certainly! Here’s a formatted version of your post suitable for Stack Overflow:

Issue with Hive Setup: Unable to Instantiate SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
I've installed the following software on my Windows machine:

Hive 2.3.9
Hadoop 3.3.1
Derby 10.14

Hadoop services are up and running.
Commands I Ran

To start DataNode and NameNode:
start-dfs


To start YARN daemons:
start-yarn


To start Derby services:
StartNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0



After this, I ran hive to start Hive. The terminal opened inside Hive, but when I try to run any commands in Hive like create database; or show databases;, I get the following error message:
2024-06-14T04:09:36,692 INFO [debdfe14-a43a-4292-8237-ae68473a95b4 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: debdfe14-a43a-4292-8237-ae68473a95b4
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
2024-06-14T04:09:53,192 INFO [debdfe14-a43a-4292-8237-ae68473a95b4 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: debdfe14-a43a-4292-8237-ae68473a95b4
2024-06-14T04:09:53,327 INFO [debdfe14-a43a-4292-8237-ae68473a95b4 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Resetting thread name to  main

I also tried to initialize the schema using the following command from the hive/bin directory:
schematool -initSchema -dbType derby

However, I received the error:
'schematool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I've verified that schematool is present inside the bin folder.
All the path variables are correctly set.
Additional Configuration
The following properties are added in hive-site.xml:
<property>
    <name>system:java.io.tmpdir</name>
    <value>C:/hive/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>system:user.name</name>
    <value>%USERNAME%</value>
</property>

Request
Can anyone help me resolve these issues and get Hive working properly?

Run just:
  schematool -initSchema -dbType derby

or
hive --service schemaTool -initSchema -dbType derby

Not inside hive terminal
